# Consistency in closing questions

Tags: discussion

Two questions have been asked on our site about global warming causing cold weather events. Both questions used the term global warming. The [first](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/424/did-global-warming-cause-the-extreme-cold-2013-14-winter-in-north-america/427#427) question was posted in April 2014 about an event in the northern hemisphere and the [second](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/are-southern-hemisphere-polar-blasts-caused-by-global-warming) question was posted in July 2015 for an event in the southern hemisphere.

Both questions were essentially asking the same thing, but the question posted in April 2014 was closed because answers could be opinion based.

The question posted in July 2015 is still open. For consistency, should both questions be closed or open?

Comment: Both questions are now open again.

Comment: That's good, We have consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first answer originally read a bit different and c[hanged a few times before eventually being closed](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/424/revisions).  Its final edit happened well after the closure and improved the question but [its nomination to reopen failed](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/968).  In its current state I think it is ok, but I won't nominate it myself for reopening as my vote is binding and may not reflect the desire of the community.  If you think it should be open, you can click the "reopen" link under the question to put in the reopen queue.  If anyone is in chat it may be easier to coordinate getting the 5 necessary reopen votes (and perhaps some upvotes if the question is worth reopening).

I agree that in its current state there seems to be some inconsistency in how the questions were treated.

Comment: Someone has already proposed that the closed question from 2014 be re-opened. I've voted to re-open it.